# How can I power the pi safely?

Tags: power, power-supply, alternative-power

I'm a student in 7th grade building a project that has to include a raspberry pi of a contest coming up in april. Long story short I have a solar panel with a 6v usb output and I would like to power the pi. I know that the pi needs around 4.75 to 5.25 approximately, so what is the best way to turn the 6v usb output into a 5v micro-usb output?

Ps. I live in a 3rd world country so many thing will not be available.
Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please check this old Q&A http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-run-the-pi-on-solar-power and let us know if it is helpful to your quest.

Comment: All of the answers, while having some merit, are unlikely to prove practical. You provide no detail of the solar panel. Does it have an in-built regulator? Is there a battery? If you connect a simple solar panel to any of the circuits below, it may work in full sunshine, but the Pi will stop working in shadow e.g. if someone leans over it.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: PLEASE READ PANDALION'S COMMENT. DO NOT TRY THIS METHOD. PLEASE! I AM NOT RESPONSIBLE FOR ANY DAMAGE THIS METHOD OCCURS. I WARN YOU, DO NOT USE THIS METHOD!**

You could buy https://www.adafruit.com/products/2236. It is a 5v regulator. Then, you can cut apart a micro usb cable and put this inside. Look at the datasheet https://www.adafruit.com/images/product-files/2236/2236.pdf. It will tell you the pinouts.

You might be able to find this in other places.

Edit:
[image: Wire diagram]

This should help. Which end you solder the wires to matters.

Comment: Thanks i've contacted my teachers and they have a spare one in the lab. The only thing I didn't really get whas the cutting up a micro usb diagram. Is there some sort of vidio you can link me to?

Comment: I am not sure, but on YouTube there is a video of adafruit creating a custom cable. I will edit my answer once I make a diagram of how to make it.

Comment: There, I added a diagram.

Comment: Pretty ghetto. Ever considered a prebuilt voltage regulator that's been safety-checked? I found  some on major resellers. Just Google voltage regulators.

Comment: @Merlin04 Are you sure the IC won't burn the house down? It only supports 250mA. The Pi needs 1A to 2A.

Comment: Thanks, guys ill bring these two ideas to my teacher. Im not that good with hardware yet so ill let him decide. :)

Comment: PandaLion98 I didn't realize that. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of risking your lives (the IC mentioned in the accepted answer only handles ~250mA), try a pre-built voltage regulator.

This has a voltmeter: http://amzn.com/B00IWOPS8K

If you're not interested in a voltmeter and only wants 5V output, try this: http://wholesaler.alibaba.com/product-detail/5v-2A-Solar-Panel-Power-Bank_60350880339.html

Or you can look for something similar in your preferred electronics store.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you buy a UBEC.  Try eBay.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two simple voltage regulator circuits that you can build, parts will be available everywhere. They are inexpensive and easy to build, parts are very common; your neighbor electronic repair will have them. A Ham-Radio friend can also be very handy! The optional fuse can be 3Amps for one Raspberry.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUi7OT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>